# How to map the C-W Shift+N for making terminal non active?

Tags: terminal

In Vim, you can invoke the terminal by `:terminal`. Then, you can treat the terminal window as a normal Vim window by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>.

I want to map this sequence to, e.g, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. I checked with `:nmap` and there is no other mapping of this sequence, i.e. the `<C-T>` is free.

I put in my `vimrc` the `nnoremap <C-T> <C-W><S-N>`, saved and then `:so %` but nothing. Then I tried the `nnoremap <C-T> <C-W>N` but again nothing.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]? Does `tnoremap <C-T> <C-W>N` do what you want? Let me know if that's what you're looking for and I'll write it as an answer...

Comment: @filbranden yes! It worked. Thank you! Please add the answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mapping keystrokes that would otherwise be sent to the job running in the terminal, you should use `:tnoremap` instead.

In your case, to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>:

```
tnoremap <C-t> <C-w>N
```

See [`:help terminal-typing`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-typing) for more details.